# Jmeter- Overwrite Global HTTP Header Manager over HTTP Header Manager available with Http Request Sampler

Tags: jmeter

For my application when I record , each HTTP request has required Headers that are maintained at individual HTTP Header Manager.
Now an Authentication token is also managed in the Header manager for every request after login. For multiple users I pass variable for this Authentication token. To make this happen I need to edit in every Header(or I do it opening jmx file in Notepad++ and then replacing all). But is there any way like using a global HTTP header manager that will override over Sample lever Headers.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Using JMeter's HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) article:

> JMeter now supports multiple Header Managers.
>   The header entries are merged to form the list for the sampler. If an entry to be merged matches an existing header name, it replaces the previous entry, unless the entry value is empty in which case any existing entry is removed. This allows one to set up a default set of headers, and apply adjustments to particular samplers.

If you don't like the situation you can uncheck "Capture HTTP Headers" box in the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

[image: Capture HTTP Headers]

Comment: If I uncheck this option, then I would need to add header at top by myself. But since I dont know what will header list for each request so I prefer recording it.

Answer (score 0):

If all headers are same throughout the script then you can remove all individual headers which are currently child of http request samplers and keep only one header manager outside of all request which will act as a global header manager and it will pass values to all requests

Comment: will removing headers from each request sampler be a manual activity. And headers are not common for all requests so I don't want to remove headers. Some Headers are common in some but not in others.